# Robust test if an expression can be coerced to character to avoid as.character error

Tags: r, character, coercion

I am looking for a reliable test (= does not throw an error) whether an expression can be converted to character.

How could I do this?

I want to avoid that calling `as.character` throws an error like eg. in case of `as.character(function() 1)` which says:

```
Error in as.character(function() 1) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Example expressions:

```
# do not throw an error in as.character
1
1:10
"test"
NA
1 + 2
# do throw an error in as.character
function() 1
new.env()
```

PS: Of course I could use `tryCatch` but is there an easier way?

**Edit 1:** I want to test if the result **value** of an expression can be coerced to a character (not the expression itself)

Comment: `as.character(quote(function() 1)` yields `[1] "function"                      "NULL"                         
[3] "1"                             "c(1, 20, 1, 31, 20, 31, 1, 1)"` though I'm not sure this qualifies as a reliable test, doesn't throw error.

Comment: Interesting idea! I have just tried it with `as.character(quote(1+2))` and the expression is then not evaluated but kept as-is: `[1] "+" "1" "2"` (instead of `3`). Since I don't know up-front what the user is passing in as argument quoting would be at risk of wrong coercing results (but maybe there is a way to handle this).

Comment: Is the operation synchronous or asynchronous and is it desirable to call/log/identify the cases that will error as noted above?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure what you mean. I simple use cases would be (in pseudo code): `if (can.be.converted.to.character(x)) log.debug(paste("x=", as.character(x)))`

Comment: Not sure this gets any closer `as.character(eval(expression(1+2)) [1] "3"` but fails for new.env(), same with serialize. Would using `promises` pkg to filter good from bad be cheating? Not that I could figure out necessarily the coding or how that would improve over tryCatch. Interesting dilema.

Comment: Currently I'd say if there is no internal function in R that can test for a possible character conversion only a `tryCatch` would work (but I wanted to be sure that I do not oversee another simple solution)

Comment: While this always seemed like it must be at minimum a two step process, perhaps [win-vector article](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/08/neat-new-seplyr-feature-string-interpolation/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there will be better answers to this question and I look forward to reading them. Wanting evaluated results assumes they are prone to evaluation, but if any unknown input is accepted, one can't be sure.

Depending upon where your pipeline is going next, explore variants of `quote` or `expression`.

```
as.character(quote(function() 1))
[1] "function"                      "NULL"                         
[3] "1"                             "c(1, 20, 1, 31, 20, 31, 1, 1)"

as.character(expression(1 + 2))
[1] "1 + 2"

as.character(eval(expression(1+2)) # works in this case
[1] "3"

as.character(eval(expression(1+2, 'A') # what would this be?
[1] "A" # so nonsense
```

Another approach might be to find out what sort of thing in the wild you're being passed and then decide what to do with it:

```
as.character(typeof(function() 1))
[1] "closure" # not safe or just pass along "closure" and move on

as.character(typeof(new.env())
[1] "environment" # not safe

as.character(typeof(expression(1+2))
[1] "expression" # safe (maybe) for further manipulation, replace typeof with eval
```

But `typeof` isn't immune to other user errors on the way to evaluated
results

```
as.character(typeof(function(x) 1, 'a'))
Error in typeof(function(x) 1, "a") : unused argument ("a")
```

I find this an interesting question because I've always assumed there was a way to render to string any object in R, though the path may be convoluted.

You'll know best regards your full project and where you are trying to control evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was perhaps somewhat unsharp in my question: I want to test the expression **result** (not the parsed expression) if it can be coerced to character. I have clarified this by editing my question